# How to find particular pattern with regex in windows batch file?

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, word-boundary

Requirement:
           Parsing a text file and need to extract a particular pattern of line to another file.In the output file i need only the lines with date followed by ERROR .

Batch file code:

```
findstr /r "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s+\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2},\\d{3} \<ERROR.*" server.log > "%CD%"/test.txt
pause
```

Input File:
Sample.log

```
2017-11-28 00:40:16,791 ERROR [org.jboss.weld.Bean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 269) WELD-000019: Error destroying an instance 
2017-11-28 00:40:16,791 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 269) [ERROR][faces context is null in context utils1]
2017-11-28 00:40:16,791 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 269) [ERROR][faces context is null in context utils1]
2017-11-28 00:40:16,791 ERROR [org.jboss.weld.Bean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 269) WELD-000019: Error destroying an instance
2017-11-28 00:40:16,791 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 269) [ERROR][faces context is null in context utils1]
2017-11-28 00:40:16,791 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 269) [ERROR][faces context is null in context utils1]
```

Expected Output:

```
2017-11-28 00:40:16,791 ERROR [org.jboss.weld.Bean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 269) WELD-000019: Error destroying an instance 
2017-11-28 00:40:16,791 ERROR [org.jboss.weld.Bean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 269) WELD-000019: Error destroying an instance
```

But currently the code return all the content in output file.
Tried word boundry \ too.

Comment: `d{3} \<ERROR.*`? Shouldn't that read `d{3}\ <ERROR.*`? But that won't sove your problem: `findstr` has a very small subset of REGEX (especially no `{count}`. Any reason to not just `findstr /c:" ERROR "`?

Comment: also no `\d`, `\s` and `+`

Comment: @Stephan yes .with /c  "ERROR"  it may filter line with error .Eg)2017-11-28 00:40:16,791 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 269)  some string with ERROR. which is not my requirement.If there is no \d, \s,+ ,count could you please suggest other way to find solution

Comment: not `/c:"ERROR"`, but `/c:" ERROR "`. Note the spaces; will not find `[ERROR]` lines. If that isn't failsafe enough, you might be interested in [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) by dbenham, which does full REGEX.

Comment: @Stephan noted the space . Ignored " ERROR"  as it filter the below 2017-11-28 00:40:16,791 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 269) [faces context is null in ERROR context utils1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FINDSTR /b /r "....-..-.....:..:..,....ERROR" "%filename1%
```

where `filename1` contains your sourcefilename should accomplish the task, given `findstr`'s restricted implementation of regex.

Comment: @johnsigeorge `/b` matches a string beginning of line, `/r` being regex. then match any 4 characters and a dash, 2 characters and a dash etc etc till error. So should you have a string with no date in the string but still contains error, it will not match it.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard thank you for the time.BTW the above solution works fine.could you please notify the non matching scenarios to know and better understanding.

Comment: @johnsigeorge You can mark the answer as correct by selecting the grey tick mark next to the question if you feel that this solution assisted you in solving your issue.

Comment: @johnsigeorge Please explain by what you mean by _could you please notify the non matching scenarios to know and better understanding_ ? if you want me to show you how it works, I would need more than a comment and that means another answer, while the answer by Magoo is perfect.